# What is the code in Arduino Wi-Fi Shield?

Tags: wifi, arduino

I want to learn [Wi-Fi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi) for embedded devices, and I come across the [**Arduino Wi-Fi shield**](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoWiFiShield). I know the shield need to connect with a basic Arduino board such as [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno). There is an **Atmel UC3A** MCU on the Wi-Fi shield, and there is a ATmega328 on the Uno. I downloaded the [Wi-Fi Shield Library](http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/WiFiShield_library.zip), there are some example codes. Yet, I found that the code in the examples are only for the Arduino Uno board.

For example, to connect to a Wi-Fi network, it just sends a command by SPI out, such as `SpiDrv::sendCmd(SET_NET_CMD, PARAM_NUMS_1);`. I think the UC3A on the Wi-Fi shield board is responsible to receive this message and do something with the Wi-Fi chip [HDG104](http://www.hd-wireless.se/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&catid=3%3acontent&id=49%3ahdg104-details).

In fact, to learn implementing Wi-Fi I think an important part is to learn how the UC3A works with the Wi-Fi chip. Hence where can I get example code which was written for the Wi-Fi shield MCU?

Also, if I want to build the hardware myself, can I just using the UC3A MCU only? UC3A is a powerful MCU, but I worry it will be too busy.

Comment: It's a low level driver. You can have a look at the linux wifi drivers if you really want to get into driver-developement as a start. Other than that, you should be able to find a datasheet for the wifichip which tells you what kind of communication it expects. Also, please read the faq, as this question is too broad to be answered in stackoverflow style.

Answer (score 1):

you can find everything on the official github repository! 
here the link to the official binary and source code of the official WiFi Shield firmware! you can also find arduino's library, everything has been uploaded just 13 days ago
enjoy
https://github.com/arduino/wifishield/tree/master/firmware